# Atom Parker Ridge intel_pstate: CPU model not supported? High power draw

Tags: intel, supermicro

I have a Supermicro A3SPI-8C-LN6PF board which features an embedded Intel Atom C5325 CPU running Proxmox (Debian 11.6, Kernel 6.2.11). `dmesg` is reporting `intel_pstate: CPU model not supported` and I'm wondering what could be the reason. I also noticed that the CPU package power draw is around ~21W when idling (`scaling_governor=ondemand`, all cores at 800 MHz)  which seems a bit high? More interestingly the power draw only increase to ~28W when running a synthetic load on all cores @ 2400 MHz.

In the BIOS the following settings are set:

- `SpeedStep (P-States)` enable
- `EIST PSD Function`: `HW_ALL` or `SW_ALL`; no difference observable.
- `Turbo Mode`: enable
- `Enable Monitor MWAIT`: enabled
- `CPU C6 Report`: enable
- `Enhanced Halt State (C1E)`: enable
- `Software Controlled T-States`: disable
- `PCIe ASPM Support (Global)`: auto